# trigger code for custom woocommerce email

Tags: email, triggers, woocommerce

I am trying to write a custom email in in woocommerce that is triggered when a registered users'
 status changes to a different level (i.e to platinum). How do I do this? Anyone know?

Thank You, Linda

Comment: I think that what you want to do is to set up roles. Maybe this wil help you https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/custom-woocommerce-roles-admin-capabilities/ or https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/6116

Comment: I am already the admin, so that will not help. I am looking for code that will recognize when a role or access level is changed by the administrator and generate an email to that user. This would be a custom email beyond the defaults that woocommerce has.